# Temporarily changing an items color

Tags: beamer, graphics, color

I am trying to write a list where the item that just appeared on screen is red while the rest of the text is black. Then when the new item is introduced, it becomes red and the first one goes back to black. Then this would go on throughout the entire list. Any ideas for how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect using the `alert` action. You can either apply the action manually to the items or have the items alert automatically:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<alert@1> test 1
  \item<alert@2> test 2
  \item<alert@3> test 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]
  \item test 1
  \item test 2
  \item test 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]